# Why am I getting this error from pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I am trying to build a python application with pyinstaller, but I get several errors whilst doing that. Any help would be appreciated!

Input:

```
iloveeveryone@iloveeveryone-GF63-8RD:~/Desktop/Computer science/Py code/App_folder$ pyinstaller app.py
```

Output:

```
40 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.3+49abfa5498
40 INFO: Python: 3.10.6
42 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.19.0-2.1-liquorix-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
42 INFO: wrote /home/iloveeveryone/Desktop/Computer science/Py code/App_folder/app.spec
43 INFO: UPX is not available.
43 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/iloveeveryone/Desktop/Computer science/Py code/App_folder']
375 INFO: checking Analysis
375 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
375 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
376 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
379 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'numpy'. Please take care they do not conflict.
380 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3456 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-distutils.py'.
3456 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/usr/lib/python3.10'
4227 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4317 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4337 INFO: Analyzing /home/iloveeveryone/Desktop/Computer science/Py code/App_folder/app.py
4362 INFO: Processing module hooks...
4362 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4363 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4372 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4446 INFO: checking Tree
4448 INFO: checking Tree
4499 WARNING: Tcl modules directory /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6/../tcl8 does not exist.
4500 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4501 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4501 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4536 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
4536 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4537 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4541 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4542 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4604 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4604 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4648 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4648 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4649 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4786 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4827 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
4865 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
4889 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
4890 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_subprocess.py'
4891 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_inspect.py'
4891 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
4892 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
4896 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
515 WARNING: Cannot find libicuuc.so.56 (needed by /home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/imageformats/../../lib/libicui18n.so.56)
516 WARNING: Cannot find libicudata.so.56 (needed by /home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/imageformats/../../lib/libicui18n.so.56)
526 WARNING: Cannot find libicudata.so.56 (needed by /home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/imageformats/../../lib/libicuuc.so.56)
6213 INFO: Looking for eggs
6213 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/.local/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 962, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 884, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/Desktop/Computer science/Py code/App_folder/app.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 409, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 696, in assemble
    self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 778, in _check_python_library
    python_lib = bindepend.get_python_library_path()
  File "/home/iloveeveryone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 1002, in get_python_library_path
    raise IOError(msg)
OSError: Python library not found: libpython3.10m.so, libpython3.10mu.so.1.0, libpython3.10m.so.1.0, libpython3.10.so, libpython3.10.so.1.0
    This means your Python installation does not come with proper shared library files.
    This usually happens due to missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of the Python installation.

    * On Debian/Ubuntu, you need to install Python development packages:
      * apt-get install python3-dev
      * apt-get install python-dev
    * If you are building Python by yourself, rebuild with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on macOS).
```

Comment: you need to share more information, like your OS would be a good start.  It says you are using debian/ubuntu is that True?  if so did you follow the instructions on the bottom? if so have you tried running the program as sudo?

Comment: Yes, my OS is Ubuntu 20.04.4
I have tried apt-get ... commands with and without sudo. Haven't tried the --enable-shared, because I am unsure on how to do that exactly.

Comment: Did you try using `sudo apt install python3-pyinstaller`

Comment: "Unable to locate package python3-pyinstaller"

Comment: Well it seems your pyinstaller doesn't have access to the standard python libs for some reason. So Maybe try uninstalling python and pyinstaller and re-install otherwise good luck

Comment: Ok, so I reinstalled both, but nothing changed. same error again.

Comment: try creating a new file and just put `print("Hello World!")` in it and run pyinstaller on that file and see if it works.  If it does then there is something in your script that is causing it, so you would have to post your code

Comment: I tried doing that, but no luck, still the same error...

Comment: okay... try creating a virtual enviornment, load the enviornement install pyinstaller into the enviornment and then do the steps from my last comment and see if that works....

Comment: If it still doesn't work, then I am out of ideas,  If it does work, then I still actually don't understand why, but at least it works

Comment: You should create a [example]